# Email form is not working

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

I have this index.html

```
<form name="index" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

<table width="450px">

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="first_name"><font color="white">Nume</font></label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top"">

  <label for="last_name"><font color="white">Prenume</font></label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="email"><font color="white">E-mail</font></label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="telephone"><font color="white">Numarul de Telefon(*)</font></label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="comments"><font color="white">Mesajul</font></label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

  <input type="submit" value="Trimite"> 

 </td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

and the send_form_email.php

```
  <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "contact@vestigedayz.com";

    $email_subject = "Comentariu Site";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "Ne pare rau dar se pare ca am intampinat o problema. ";

        echo "Erorile sunt:<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Te rugam sa dai backspace si sa refaci corect.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('Ne pare rau dar se pare ca am intampinat o problema.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'E-mail-ul nu este corect.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'Numele tau nu este corect.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'Prenumele tau nu este corect.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'Sectiunea de mesaj nu este corecta..<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Detaliile sunt mai jos.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "Nume: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Prenume: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telefon: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Mesaj: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Multumim ca ne-ai scris. Iti vom raspunde cat de curand !



<?php

}

?>
```

Everything works OK, but I don't receive any email. Why? Everything looks to be OK what should I add or remove? I can't figure it out. I read this from a tutorial on the internet how you should create a contact form.

Comment: there can be multiple reasons for this, are you testing it on local system or on server? you have to check if email settings are enable in php.ini or on server

Comment: `@mail` —`@`!? Why are you suppressing error messages if it doesn't work and you don't know why?!